# Creating project in netbeans shwoing nothing except source index and include path folder

Tags: php, netbeans, yii

Please solve my issue, i was using netbeans 8.0.2 and all the work was fine, i can easily create projects etc.. but somehow i was creating new project using cmd command, all the old projects have been deleted, even my www folder in wamp were also deleted. I thought it would be a virus, so i reinstall wamp and reinstall netbeans 8.0.2.. The problem I am facing is that when i try to make a new project, it using php, yii framework... i got only 2 folder, source index and include path... just like in this link (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html).. :( but in old netbeans whenever i created a project, i had all folders.. extension, controller, modules, etc.. can any one tell me what is happening with netbeans ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is a problem with Netbeans. In Netbeans, you have to open a project with existing sources, if you have already code to working with.

1. Open Netbeans
2. in the Menu choose, **File > New Project**
3. In the **New Project wizard**-Window, select Category **PHP**
4. On the right side of the window (Projects) choose **PHP Application with existing Sources**
5. Click **Next**
6. In the **New PHP Project with Existing Sources**-Window you can choose the location of your existing codebase with the **Browse** Option in the **Source Folders** row
7. Click **Finish**

Your manually created sourcecode should by editable with Netbeans now.

[image]